# powershell: assigning the value of a variable instead of the type

Tags: .net, arrays, powershell

for example, if i run the code below, $ProgramName is a string not a array which i want.  How can i take the value of $cncprograms and add it to $ProgramName retaining the array type?

```
$ProgramName =@()
$ProgramName = JOHN 
$cncPrograms = DOH 
$ProgramName += $cncPrograms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you need:

```
$ProgramName =@()
$ProgramName += "JOHN" 
$cncPrograms = "DOH" 
$ProgramName += $cncPrograms
$programname 

JOHN
DOH
```

in your code you are re-assign a string value to the variable:

`$ProgramName = "JOHN"` # now the variable is of type string (no more an [object[]] object array)

that's way `$ProgramName += $cncPrograms` give a result of "JOHNDOH"

Comment: You could also combine the first two lines into an explicit array.
$Programname=@("John")
$cncPrograms="Doh"
$ProgramName+=$cncPrograms

Answer (score 0):

Type constrain the variable:

```
[Array]$ProgramName = @()
$ProgramName = 'JOHN'
$cncPrograms = 'DOH'
$ProgramName += $cncPrograms
$ProgramName
```